# Ordering a list of elements without losing the event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kfs7e/) list :

```
<ul>
    <li id="6">
        list 6: somethings
    </li>

    <li id="2">
        list 2: somethings
    </li>    

    <li id="4">
        list 4: somethings
    </li>    

    <li id="5">
        list 5: somethings
    </li>        

    <li id="0">
        list 0: somethings
    </li>    
</ul>
```

and I'd like (with Javascript/jQuery) order these elements by the id (ASC) keeping the event handler for each element.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: The event handlers won't be detached, but your notion of ordering is wrong, because you can't have an integer ID attribute, neither can one start with an integer.

Comment: ? I mean the ID for each <li>

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, too. You can't have an integer as the ID of the element. It's not valid.

Comment: @Shef - That's not the case for HTML5. The only rules are that an `id` must be unique in the document, contain at least one character, and contain no spaces: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Is not so important if it evalutates number as string instead of integer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just assign the ID's into an array and use `sort()`:

```
var a = [];
$("ul li").attr('id',function(i,e){
    a.push(e);
});
$.each(a.sort(),function(i,e){
    $("#"+e).appendTo('ul');
});
```

You are never removing them from the list, just moving them around. Click handler stays intact:

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/nVLqR/

Comment: Not sure why this works (append should add another one, not move), but it works :)

Comment: Because append should "append" another one, not move :)

Comment: @markzzz It works the same way if you use the standard DOM methods, https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild "If the node already exists it is removed from current parent node, then added to new parent node." and "If child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild moves it from its current position to the new position (i.e. there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node)."

Comment: I doesnt know about this. Thanks :)

Comment: Fair play Niklas, didn't realise that :-)

Comment: +1 for the usage of the function(i,e) - I never remember this

Answer (score 6):

This should work fine. Using `detach` preserves any events associated with the element. You then use a custom sort function to compare the `id` attributes of each `li` element.

```
var ul = $("ul");
var li = ul.children("li");
li.detach().sort(function(a, b) {
   var compA = $(a).prop("id");
   var compB = $(b).prop("id");
   return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
});
ul.append(li);
```

See an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5tnS/2/). A click event is attached to the `li` with ID "6". After the list has been reordered, that click event is still handled.

Answer (score 1):

I think to order them you'll had to remove and add them back into the DOM... and therefore you'll certainly lose the event handler. Are you in control of the handler, can you rebind or use `live()` instead?

The alternative would be to absolutely position the `li` elements and use the css position properties (`top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`) to move them around, this will keep them in the same order in the DOM, but render them in your desired order.t

Comment: You can reorder them without removing them.

Comment: Can you? Please share your info.

Comment: @Niklas : can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

This example work for me:

```
var mylist = $('.item').detach().sort(function (a, b) { 
    return $(a).find(selector).html() > $(b).find(selector).html();
});
$("#container").html(mylist);
```

or if you want to sort with other informations:

```
var mylist = $('.item').detach().sort(function (a, b) { 
    return $(a).find(selector).attr('data-title')() > $(b).find(selector).attr('data-title');
});
$("#container").html(mylist);
```